# How do I set the background color of Excel cells using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

As part of a VBA program, I have to set the background colors of certain cells to green, yellow or red, based on their values (basically a health monitor where green is okay, yellow is borderline and red is dangerous).

I know how to set the values of those cells, but how do I set the background color.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use either:

```
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 28
```

or

```
ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
```

Comment: In the first example, how do you know which color the ColorIndex points to?

Comment: @awe - The colors and numbers are here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296089(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 13):

This is a perfect example of where you should use the macro recorder. Turn on the recorder and set the color of the cells through the UI. Stop the recorder and review the macro. It will generate a bunch of extraneous code, but it will also show you syntax that works for what you are trying to accomplish. Strip out what you don't need and modify (if you need to) what's left.

Answer (score 1):

or alternatively you could not bother coding for it and use the 'conditional formatting' function in Excel which will set the background colour and font colour based on cell value.

There are only two variables here so set the default to yellow and then overwrite when the value is greater than or less than your threshold values.

Comment: this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Do a quick 'record macro' to see the color number associated with the color you're looking for (yellow highlight is 65535). Then erase the code and put

```
Sub Name()
Selection.Interior.Color = 65535 '(your number may be different depending on the above)
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe explain why and how a numeric literal can replace an RGB(,,) construct, and also possibly express the literal in hexadecimal `Selection.Interior.Color = &H00FFFF` where each pair of hexadecimal digits defines respectively the value of Red, Green and Blue in the range `&H00` to `&HFF`.

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't work if you use Function, but works if you Sub. However, you cannot call a sub from a cell using formula.