# Excel - Highlight selected/active cell keeping old color

Tags: excel

there is here ([How do I set the background color of Excel cells using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365125/how-do-i-set-the-background-color-of-excel-cells-using-vba#365131)) some information about highlighting an active/selected cell in excel, but I cannot manage to restore the old background color of the cell that was set prior to the selection. Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this issue? Thanks!!!

Comment: Before you update the color, store the old color and cell reference in a global variable and then change it back when you select another cell.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes, the logic makes sense, but since I am a VBA newbie, I would appreciate any piece of code.

Comment: Can you show me an attempt you've made before I give you the code?  That's kind of what Stackoverflow is all about.

Comment: Sure, that's all about my artwork:

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'ActiveSheet.Unprotect "Password"
    'Sh.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 27   'change colorindex to select background color
    'MsgBox ("Background color: " & Target.Interior.ColorIndex)
    
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 32        'change colorindex to select active cell color
    
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

so, this is my solution in case someone wants to use it:

In a module put this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public oldCellAddr As String
Public oldCellBackgroundColor As Long

Public Function InitializeGlobalVariables() As Boolean

    Set oldCellAddr = ""
    Set oldCellBackgroundColor = 0
    
End Function
```

In the workbook sheet put this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim thisCellAddr As String

    thisCellAddr = ActiveCell.Address
    
    If (oldCellAddr <> "" And thisCellAddr <> oldCellAddr) Then
        Range(oldCellAddr).Interior.ColorIndex = oldCellBackgroundColor
    End If
    
    oldCellBackgroundColor = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
    oldCellAddr = thisCellAddr
    
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 24

End Sub
```

Done.